# Import json within mongodb collection?

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb

I'd like to import a .json file in a MongoDB collection as a field, where the imported data can essentially work as a subdocument with the field label. Is this possible? I'm using Django for my web framework and file uploads.

Right now the data model looks like this in Django:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trips/files/', null = True, blank = True)
```

I would like the "file" field to be a .json import that reads subfields into the document; in Mongo the data model would look like this for example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e18e9b0593b827d141e9c6d"
    },
    "name": "f"
    "file": {
        "field1": "asdf"
        "field2": 1234
        "field3": {
            "fieldA": "3"
            "fieldB": "876"
        }
    }
}
```

where the fields under "file" are in the .json file that is imported. Obviously the real json would be more sophisticated but this is just a simple example.

If this is possible please let me know, being able to import these .jsons and have them handled correctly within Mongo is all I need to be able to get what I need running to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PyMongo is pretty helpful. It offers the `insert_one()` function that works identically to a typical mongo insert. Check out the documentation [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/index.html). 
You might need a function based on your model. You also would need to incorporate the PyMongo requirements to utilize this.

Try this:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:27017")
db = client.your_database #Database
col = db.your_collection #Collection

class Trip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trips/files/', null = True, blank = True)

    def insert_into_collection(self):
        col.insert_one({'uploaded_file':file})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a dumb question but do I need to call the database in models.py? I already have a connection set up in the project's settings file. Would there be a way to reference that instead of opening the connection with MongoClient() or am I being dumb and not understanding how this is supposed to work? Thanks anyway though because this is already helping me.

Comment: @frz you could instead create a connection through your `views.py` that would insert the file into the mongo database. That is most likely a simpler solution. It roughly would have to function upon a user's file upload, then save that file itself into the db.